# Use a postgres extension as a non-privileged user

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

### The Problem

I have the following trigger function that uses the `moddatetime` extension:

```
/* BEFORE UPDATE trigger - Updates "entity_version.updated_on", setting it to the current UTC time. */
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS moddatetime;  -- Needs superuser privileges!

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trig_entity_version_before_update
ON entity_version;

CREATE TRIGGER trig_entity_version_before_update
    BEFORE UPDATE
    ON entity_version
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE moddatetime(updated_on);  -- updated_on is TIMESTAMP type
```

The trigger works perfectly fine, but the issue is that the first line (`CREATE EXTENSION`) requires super-user privileges. Since these databases are going to be created by users (via a script) I don't want them the user that makes these databases and triggers to have super user access.

### What I've tried

As a first step, running the script as a super user works fine, as you'd expect.

Naturally, the next step would be to separate the creation of the extension as a superuser from the trigger creation script. But doing that, if I run the above script without `CREATE EXTENSION` line, I get the following error:

```
function moddatetime() does not exist
```

Which I suppose makes sense given that the script never declares `moddatetime`, but I cannot find anywhere in the documentation how to define the extension as available without using `CREATE EXTENSION`. Surely there must be a way to import or use an extension without having the create it? Something akin to:

```
USING EXTENSION moddatetime;  -- Does something like this exist?

... rest of the trigger script ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the extension installed if you want to use it.

PostgreSQL v13 introduces the notion of a *trusted extension*, which can be installed by non-superusers with the `CREATE` privilege on the database, but this extension is not among them. So upgrading won't fix the problem.

You could connect to `template1` as superuser and create the extension there. Then it would automatically be present in all newly created databases.

But frankly, I don't see the point. You can do the same thing with a regular PL/pgSQL trigger – only the performance wouldn't be as good.

Comment: I suppose writing a little trigger function isn't too big of a deal, I just find it annoying I can't use the extension for what I think is a pretty normal use-case. I'll just go with a custom trigger solution and post it as a secondary answer.

Comment: You could take it up with the pgsql-hackers mailing list - at first glance, I see no reason why the extension couldn't be trusted.

Answer (score 1):

As per @laurenz-albe his suggestion, I've just stepped off of using the extension for this particular use-case. Fortunately, writing a function to do what the extension does is relatively trivial. I'll include it here for reference in case someone is looking specifically to replace `moddatetime`.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fn_entity_version_before_update() CASCADE;

CREATE FUNCTION fn_entity_version_before_update() RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS
$fn_body$
BEGIN
    NEW.updated_on = NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'utc';
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$fn_body$;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trig_entity_version_before_update
ON entity_version;

CREATE TRIGGER trig_entity_version_before_update
    BEFORE UPDATE
    ON entity_version
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_entity_version_before_update();
```